# Use value of previous column in the SQL insert query

Tags: sql

I am trying following query to insert data from a file. How do I calculate TOTAL_HOURS from in_date and out_date? I know we can not select them as "as in_date" and use it later. It was for illustration purpose only.
The script is reading data from a file and it is not stored in database yet.

```
insert into Table_A (
    Id,
    IN_DATE,
    OUT_DATE,
    TOTAL_HOURS,
)
values (
    1,
    '2021-10-04 07:00:00' as in_date,
    '2021-10-04 07:00:00' as out_date,
    DATEDIFF(second, out_date, in_date) / 3600.0
);
```

Comment: a generated column wood simplify your qiery, else you need to use the dates and not the column names in the datediff, but to be honest , you do you need the column anyway, you can calculate it and so you need to update always the column too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `INSERT` a **static** `datetime` using `TIMESTAMPDIFF`:

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (Id, IN_DATE, OUT_DATE, TOTAL_HOURS)
SELECT 1, '2021-10-04 07:00:00', '2021-10-04 08:00:00',
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, '2021-10-04 07:00:00', '2021-10-04 08:00:00')
```

If you want to `INSERT` a **dynamic** `datetime` using data from another table (i.e. `Table_B` to `Table_A` using a **key**):

```
INSERT INTO Table_A (Id, IN_DATE, OUT_DATE, TOTAL_HOURS)
SELECT Id, IN_DATE, OUT_DATE,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, IN_DATE, OUT_DATE) FROM Table_B WHERE Id = 1
```

**Result:**

| Id | IN_DATE | OUT_DATE | TOTAL_HOURS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-10-04 07:00:00 | 2021-10-04 08:00:00 | 1 |

Fiddle [here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/TsXRUDuD)

---

To `INSERT` from a `.csv` file use the `LOAD DATA INFILE` command and add the `TIMESTAMPDIFF` calculation to the `SET` clause:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'c:/tmp/discounts_2.csv'
INTO TABLE Table_A
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(Id,@IN_DATE,@OUT_DATE)
SET IN_DATE=@IN_DATE,
OUT_DATE=@OUT_DATE,
TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, @IN_DATE, @OUT_DATE);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am reading a file and inserting data into tables so data would be dynamic and I do not have that data in the temporary table either. How can I achieve above?

Comment: What type of file? csv?

Comment: Yes, It is a CSV file.

Comment: Are you using the LOAD DATA INFILE command? You can add the TIMESTAMPDIFF to the SET clause.

Comment: Also, are you dynamically trying to do it like my second query or static like the first?

Comment: I’ve updated my answer to include the insert using a csv.

Comment: How can I update below query with SET so that there is no loading of data from CSV?


insert into Table_A (
    Id,
    IN_DATE,
    OUT_DATE,
    TOTAL_HOURS,
)
values (
    1,
    '2021-10-04 07:00:00' as in_date,
    '2021-10-04 07:00:00' as out_date,
    DATEDIFF(second, out_date, in_date) / 3600.0
);

Comment: “There is no loading of data from csv”, I’m confused now? You are loading from a csv or are not? regardless, all three of my answers above should help you.  CSV/static insert/dynamic insert. :). Let me know.